# How to keep secure info out of App Engine logs?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I've written a simple login system with Google App Engine, and I want to make sure that an admin (with access to the whole admin dashboard) can't see the passwords that users are submitting. Specifically, my concern is with the logs. Is using POST's (as opposed to GET's, which are bad for obvious reasons) enough to keep parameters like passwords out of the logs? If not, how do I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have to make sure that this not very trustworthy individual has a role of a "viewer" in your app. A user with a role of developer or owner can see anything he wants. For example, he can upload a new version of the app (which may not be even related to your app) that will load all passwords from the Datastore and email them somewhere. Or this app will ask users for a password and send it somewhere.

Second, unless you add code specifically for logging passwords (or any other POST parameters), App Engine logs will not contain this information.

You may find this article interesting: [Demystifying the App Engine request logs](http://blog.notdot.net/2011/06/Demystifying-the-App-Engine-request-logs)

Comment: So it's not even worth trying to protect data against a compromised admin account, and instead one just has to bank on 2FA and such to prevent an admin from becoming compromised?

Comment: App Engine keeps track of some admin actions, like uploading a new app version, which may prevent some types of obvious fraud. Most people will not take a risk to openly sabotage a company that has their personal data, but there are no absolute guarantees. A system admin is a key security risk regardless of the platform that you use.